# Unexpected output from oddSublists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have just bought *Mathematica* and I'm in the process of plowing through Shifrin's great book. On page 74 the function `oddSublists` doesn't give me the expected output.

Since I'm a true beginner, I of course suspect mistakes on my behalf.
I get: `{{}, {, 2}, {, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}`

However the function `oddSublistsNew` gives me the expected output.`{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}`

Anyone had similar experience?

And here is the code I forgot to include:

```
Clear[oddSublists];
oddSublists[x_List] := 
 Part[x, Union[
   Flatten[Cases[
     Map[First, 
      Split[Position[x, _?OddQ], First[#1] == First[#2] &], {2}], 
      y_List /; OddQ[Length[y]]]]]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.Stackexchange. We prefer self-contained questions, so it would be better if you could post the code for `oddSublists` and ask why it doesn't work.

Comment: I suspect a transcription error, so as @Pickett notes  please post the code you are actually using.

Comment: With `complextestlist1 = Range /@ Range[6]` the code you posted gives me the expected output.

Comment: @Pickett: That's odd. I run the `complextestlist1 = Range /@ Range[6]`on the line before oddSublists[] and that output looks correct: `{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 
  5, 6}}`but the function returns the before mentioned output.

Comment: @MathLind Try restarting your kernel and run the code again. Can't see why it would help in this particular scenario, but it's a thing to try.

Comment: On my machine `oddSublists @ Range @ Range @ 6` produces `{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}}` using the code in the question.

Comment: @Pickett && Mr.Wizard: Thank you for your checking. The problem doesn't go away, inspite of restarting computer and kernel. I have successfully tried every line of code in the book, until now. I honestly have no clue.

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this problem?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: No unfortunately not. Its the only code so far in Shifrin's book I haven't been able to get the expected result from. I'm currently on page 142 and everything else is going swimmingly. Thank you for your altruism :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I have found the cause of my problem. 
Since I do not use an English keyboard, I often need to press Alt and Shift keys to obtain a `}` or `]`. 
Sometimes I accidentally press ctrl or other key combinations. This seems to create three problems:
1. The notebook alerts with an orange color despite no visible errors. 
2. The notebook alerts with a brown color and backspacing seems to be hampered. 
3. The code does not work, in spite of no visible problems.

With errors 1 and 2, it is often sufficient to remove one or a few lines. But with error 3, I needs to erase the whole package because I cannot see where the error is.

Since practice makes perfect, these errors occur more rarely for me.

This is so far the best solution I have found.
If anyone knows a better method for visualizing hidden characters, please comment.

Leonid Shifrins advice to develop  more complex code by first writing and evaluating one-liners, seems at this point very relevant and appropriate.

Comment: You could put a double quote on the start and on the end of your code and evaluate. My guess is that the invisible character should be visible in the output. Another option is to use Ctrl-Shift-E (Show Expression) on your cell to reveal its internal structure. The result may sometimes somewhat overwhelming but with some luck you should be able to spot the offender, remove it and restore the cell with the same key code.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Certainly an overwhelming output, but this gives me a new handle on the problem. Haven't seen those tricks before. Thanks.